# Calling wmic with local user from linux box to windows (NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: linux, windows, user-management, wmi

This question has been asked in various forms but none of the solutions worked for me.

I am trying to run `icinga` from a linux box and one the plugins uses `WMI` queries. It's failing, so I decided to run simple `wmic` queries to find the issue. I use the following query:

```
wmic -U locallogin%'localpass' //myserver.domain.net "select * from Win32_Bios"
```

where `locallogin` is a local administrator and `localpass` is the password.
Unfortunately I get the following error:

> [wmi/wmic.c:196:main()] ERROR: Login to remote object.
>   NTSTATUS: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED - Access denied

However I get a successful response when I use a domain login. So my theory is that this has nothing to do with network settings but is a user credentials/permissions problem but I have no idea where to look. I should note that I have successfully used a local admin account on another machine on my domain but I can't find any discrepancy between the local user on it and the local user on this other machine.

- I have confirmed firewall settings and the like which I don't think are an issue since I can use a domain login.
- I have tried explicitly adding the `locallogin` to `WMI` security via `wmimgmt.msc` (even though local admins can do it already).
- I have gone into `DCOMCNFG` -> `Component Services` -> `Computers` -> `My Computer` -> `Properties` -> Under COM Security and added the user to both sections.
- I have tried [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/587826/wmi-wmic-linux-agent-query-error-ntstatus-nt-status-access-denied) but it didn't work plus since I can run my queries with a domain login I don't think that is the issue.
- I have run both these (just in case) from `cmd` in elevated permissions: `netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote desktop" new enable=Yes` and 
  `winrm quickconfig`.

Is there something I am forgetting? I've removed and re-added the local user, triple checked for typos, etc. but I've been stuck for 2 days now. Any help is appreciated.

**Further Info**

I've also tried running the following from Powershell on another Windows box from within the same domain:

```
Get-WmiObject -ComputerName myserver.domain.net -Class Win32_Process -Credential locallogin
```

Where `locallogin` is the user that exists on the remote server. This fails with

> Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

and in the event log on the remote server I see this:

> Failure Information:
>       Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
>       Status:         0xC000006D
>       Sub Status:     0xC0000064

However I am 110% sure the password is good and the user exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course immediately after I post a bounty it starts working. I didn't reboot or change anything. [I have no idea why it is working now](https://images-cdn.9gag.com/photo/anYZ9Eo_700b.jpg).

Comment: It is only working BECAUSE you posted a bounty!